# Qt4 to Qt5 Migration Linker Warning (and Error) with VS2013

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake, qt5

I have a project that I originally started developing using Qt4 and am now working on migrating to Qt5. After a couple hours reworking some code and removing newly deprecated calls, I was able to get the project to compile but now I'm having problems getting it to link.

I am using CMake to generate the project files. I started migrating by first modifying the "solutions's" CMake file and replacing:

```
#############################################
# find QT
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

# configure QT modules
SET(QT_USER_QTCORE TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTMAIN TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTWEBKIT TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTNETWORK TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTSQL TRUE)

SET(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTUITOOLS TRUE)

# include QT requirements
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
#############################################
```

with (this needs to be cleaned up)

```
#############################################
# find QT
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Concurrent REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Network REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Sql REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5WebKit REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5WebKitWidgets REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Xml REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${Qt5Concurrent_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${QT5_FOLDER}
    "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/msvc2012_64/include"
)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
#############################################
```

After this, I commented out all my calls to `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()` and started adding them back in one at a time. My project uses [Log4Qt](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net/) and since that has no other dependencies on other subdirectories, it was the first subproject I started working on.

In Log4Qt's CMakeLists.txt file, I simply changed `QT4_WRAP_CPP(MOC_SOURCE_FILES ${MOC_HEADERS})` to `QT5_WRAP_CPP(MOC_SOURCE_FILES ${MOC_HEADERS})`, with `MOC_HEADERS` being defined as all the necessarily MOC'd headers in Log4Qt.

When I load this up in VS2013 and build, it compiles fine but linking throws the same warnings for every moc_*:

```
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: static struct QMetaObject const Log4Qt::StringMatchFilter::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@StringMatchFilter@Log4Qt@@2UQMetaObject@@B) already defined in log4qt_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4006: "private: static void __cdecl Log4Qt::StringMatchFilter::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@StringMatchFilter@Log4Qt@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in log4qt_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl Log4Qt::StringMatchFilter::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@StringMatchFilter@Log4Qt@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) already defined in log4qt_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual void * __cdecl Log4Qt::StringMatchFilter::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@StringMatchFilter@Log4Qt@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) already defined in log4qt_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual int __cdecl Log4Qt::StringMatchFilter::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@StringMatchFilter@Log4Qt@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in log4qt_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
>moc_stringmatchfilter.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
```

I continued with my migration and continue to get the same warnings. For example, here is the entire CMakeLists.txt file for one of the subprojects:

> PROJECT(Network)
>
> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
>
> SET (SOURCE_FILES     RequestCache.cpp    WebClient.cpp )
>
> SET (MOC_HEADERS  RequestCache.h  WebClient.h )
>
> SET (HEADER_FILES     ${MOC_HEADERS} )
>
> SET(DEPENDENCY_LIST   log4qt  Core )
>
> ADD_LIBRARY(Network STATIC    ${SOURCE_FILES}     ${HEADER_FILES}
>     ${MOC_SOURCE_FILES}      )
>
> QT5_USE_MODULES(Network Network)

And (some of) the warnings:

```
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl owl::WebClient::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@WebClient@owl@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) already defined in Network_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual void * __cdecl owl::WebClient::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@WebClient@owl@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) already defined in Network_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: virtual int __cdecl owl::WebClient::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@WebClient@owl@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in Network_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4006: "private: static void __cdecl owl::WebClient::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@WebClient@owl@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in Network_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: static struct QMetaObject const owl::WebClient::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@WebClient@owl@@2UQMetaObject@@B) already defined in Network_automoc.obj; second definition ignored
moc_WebClient.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
```

Pressing ahead still, I went ahead and added all the relevant projects and attempted to build the project's executable. And then I got the following errors (the executable's project name being 'Owl') (this is an excerpt of the errors, not the full listing):

```
error LNK2005: "public: static struct QMetaObject const owl::PostListWebView::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@PostListWebView@owl@@2UQMetaObject@@B) already defined in moc_PostListView.obj   C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl owl::PostListWebView::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@PostListWebView@owl@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in moc_PostListView.obj   C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl owl::BoardTreeView::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@BoardTreeView@owl@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) already defined in moc_BoardTreeView.obj    C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "public: virtual void * __cdecl owl::BoardTreeView::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@BoardTreeView@owl@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) already defined in moc_BoardTreeView.obj C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "public: virtual int __cdecl owl::BoardTreeView::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@BoardTreeView@owl@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in moc_BoardTreeView.obj    C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl owl::BoardTreeView::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@BoardTreeView@owl@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) already defined in moc_BoardTreeView.obj  C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl owl::ConfiguringBoardDlg::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@ConfiguringBoardDlg@owl@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) already defined in moc_ConfiguringBoardDlg.obj  C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
error LNK2005: "public: virtual void * __cdecl owl::ConfiguringBoardDlg::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@ConfiguringBoardDlg@owl@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) already defined in moc_ConfiguringBoardDlg.obj   C:\vbulletin\cmake\deltas\Win64\Deltas\Owl_automoc.obj  Owl
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to fix this in my CMake files? I fail to see how I'm configuring CMake incorrectly or is there's something else I'm missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels like you didn't clean your project build directory properly. Also if your CMake version is high enough you can try using `CMAKE_AUTOMOC`. More details [here](http://blogs.kde.org/2011/11/01/cool-new-stuff-cmake-286-automoc).

Comment: I had CMAKE_AUTOMOC on and that was part of my problem. I was MOC'ing in my individual project files too. My guess is that I was "double MOC'ing" and therefore the linker was seeing two definitions of each MOC'd function. I tried removing the individual MOC calls but that generated another error. So, instead I turned off automoc and that seemed to fix it! So your answer lead me in the right direction! Thank you so much!!